# ST_Intersection fills up LIMIT with empty geometry points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, null-geometry

I have managed to get the intersection between a circle around a point and objects in a geometry using this PostGIS query:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(sea_level.geom, ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.01667,55.71667), 4326), 3006), 10000))
FROM sea_level
LIMIT 20000;
```

This works fine if I set the limit high enough to get "valuable" objects, but most of the returned rows are just "empty" objects (as GeoJSON):

```
{"type":"Polygon","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:3006"}},"coordinates":[]}
```

If I set the limit too low, I will only get these "empty" rows, and none of the valuable rows with the actual intersecting objects.
What are these "empty" rows and why are they returned?

Comment: Order in the result set is *random* without an `ORDER BY` (except with a *Primary Key* column in the `SELECT`), and the result set in your query includes **all** rows in`sea level` without a filter expression (e.g. `WHERE`, `JOIN`), so also those that don't have a spatial overlap (which are `NULL` then). Hint: do not use a buffer for proximity filter - use `ST_DWithin` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use ST_DWithin first:
```
SELECT geom
FROM sea_level
WHERE ST_DWithin(sea_level.geom,ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.01667,55.71667), 4326), 3006), 64)
LIMIT 10;
```
returns one single row contains a huge geometry covering the whole dataset. If I change the distance to below 64, it returns no rows (not even any null rows). So, why does it not return any null rows, and why only one row with the whole geometry of the dataset, while the ST_Intersects query returns what I want, i.e. multiple rows with intersecting objects, but also more than I want, the null rows?

Comment: How many features you have in the table "sea_level"? Without testing it looks like your query is returning one line per each feature in the sea_level, with empty geometry if there is no intersection.

Comment: There are 1356 features in sea_level

Comment: ... and yes, you are correct, all 1356 features are returned, with empty geometry when no intersection. What is the right way to just get the intersecting features?

Comment: So, I just added a filter to the ST_Intersection  query using ST_IsEmpty, so now it just returns what I want. Now I am wondering if this the right way to do it, or if I should try to get the ST_DWithin working?

Comment: What remains after removing what ST_IsEmpty finds gives the right result. I think that using ST_Dwithin was not right advice in this case because you do want to get the intersections, not just to find if features are close enough. DWithin could make the query faster by taking care of preliminary filtering (do not even try to compute intersection for far away features) but if speed is not critical just stay with your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Because my comment about proximity searches seems to have caused confusion: the correct way to implement a high performance proximity filter to help with this specific scenario would be:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(sl.geom, ST_Buffer(poi, 10000)) AS geom
FROM   sea_level AS sl
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.01667, 55.71667), 4326), 3006) AS poi
WHERE  ST_DWithin(sl.geom, poi, 10000)
;
```

Here

- `ST_DWithin` quickly filters for all `sl.geom` that *would not fall inside the `ST_Buffer`*, and thus

  - reduces the actual (and costly) `ST_Intersection` operation, on (less but still costly) `ST_Buffer`'ed geometries, to only those `sl.geom` that are relevant
  - in effect does not include `NULL` values for non-intersecting features
- the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` moves the point-of-interest creation (`poi`) to a cache-able function value expression, mainly to avoid repeated calls

Without the need to intersect an `ST_Buffer`, the filter would e.g. use a call to `ST_Intersects`. In general, *for where it's applicable, and functions interchangeable*, the benefit of using `ST_DWithin` is its algorithmic complexity, which *may* (dependent on geometry types) be lesser than that of a spatial overlap check except for the worst-case.

---

If you see any significant performance boost is questionable: the planner may neglect any indexes completely for a table that small, and a few thousand spatial overlap calculations on simple point buffers are fairly fast these days. But add two orders of magnitude to the row count, or more complex geometries, and the difference in execution times will be *minutes* to *seconds*.

Comment: One minor point - the buffer polygon is not a full circle, so it's possible that there will be some geometries which satisfy the `ST_DWithin` distance, but still do not intersect the buffer.  To avoid this it might be better to use `ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer...))` as the condition.

Comment: @dr_jts and that's a good catch. Yet, buffers for proximity searches are just so bad. And after all, can a buffer ever be the circle it promises to be...?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid returning empty intersection results, run the intersection only on geometries which actually intersect by using a `ST_Intersects` condition:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(sea_level.geom, poi.geom)
FROM sea_level JOIN
  (SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(
              ST_MakePoint(13.01667,55.71667), 4326), 3006), 10000) AS geom) poi
ON ST_Intersects(sea_level.geom, poi.geom)
LIMIT 20000;
```

This also improves performance, because:

- `ST_Intersects` takes advantage of a spatial index on `sea_level`
- the `ST_Intersects` calculation is faster than `ST_Intersection`, so it's better to use it first

Comment: Exact with respect to the buffered geometry, for a small tradeoff in performance. Can't have it all ,)